# How do I write the junit test for a thread pool executor configuration (AsyncConfig)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, threadpool

Following is my configuration for a thread pool executor-

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {

    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {   //should not return null
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(30);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(30);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1000);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

I need to write a Unit test for the same. I do understand how to write unit tests for services and controllers, but being new to this stuff, I am not sure what to test in case of configurations. For instance in the above code I can verify that the return value of the function is not null. But I don't understand how to do that either, because no where in the project am I calling the 'asyncExecutor' function. All I am doing is annotating the function (that needs to be run using the thread pool executor) with

```
@Async("asyncExecutor")
```

Please help me with this, and also any other stuff that I can test for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JUnit and Mockito to write a Unit test for this configuration bean. Example -

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

public class AsyncConfigTest {

    @Test
    public void testAsyncExecutor() {
        AsyncConfig asyncConfig = new AsyncConfig();
        Executor executor = asyncConfig.asyncExecutor();
        assertNotNull(executor);

        // Verify the executor properties
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) executor;
        assertEquals(30, threadPoolTaskExecutor.getCorePoolSize());
        assertEquals(30, threadPoolTaskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize());
        assertEquals(1000, threadPoolTaskExecutor.getQueueCapacity());
        assertEquals("Async-", threadPoolTaskExecutor.getThreadNamePrefix());
    }

}
```

Mokito to mock `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

public class MyServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void testAsyncMethod() {
        // Create a mock of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executorMock = Mockito.mock(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.class);
        MyService myService = new MyService(executorMock);

        // Call the async method
        myService.doAsyncTask();

        // Verify that the executor was used
        verify(executorMock).execute(Mockito.any(Runnable.class));
    }

}
```

You're creating a mock `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` object and passing it to your `MyService` class in the preceding test. Then you call an async method on the `MyService` class and check that the executor was used to perform the async task.

Comment: Please mark it answered